# Next.js router create query string and query string array

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next-router

I use Next.js on my project and I need to make a dynamic query string. I use this code:

```js
const createQuery = (filter) => {
  let currentPath = router.pathname;
  let filterSize = Object.keys(filter).length;

  filterSize != 0 ? (currentPath += "?") : null;

  Object.keys(filter).map(function (key, index) {
    currentPath +=
      key + "=" + filter[key] + (index === filterSize - 1 ? "" : "&");
  });

  router.push(currentPath);
};
```

It works but I don't send an array to query string. How can I do this? Also, ss there an easier way to create a query string in Next.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to simplify your code

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  var1: "value",
  var2: "value2",
  arr: "foo",
});
console.log(params.toString());
//Prints "var1=value&var2=value2&arr=foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily pass dynamic query strings using [nextjs/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

`Router.push` accepts `query` as an object which will be converted to query parameters.

for example:

```
 Router.push({
  pathname: currentPath,
  query: {
     page: 1,
     skip: 10
  }
})
// results into currentPath?page=1&skip=10
```